# query to find not matching Doctype ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table called `Documents` with in the table is the following columns.

```
DocID,DocTypeID,Invoice,Invoice_Date
```

What I'm looking for is to get all invoice that appear in DocTypeID `5bef8666` but does not appear in DocTypeID `923847f9`.

***Example***

```
DocID,DocTypeID,Invoice,Invoice_Date 
00001,923847f9,  00001 ,24/01/2016
00002,923847f9,  00002 ,24/01/2016 
00003,923847f9,  00003 ,24/01/2016
00004,923847f9,  00004 ,24/01/2016 
00005,5bef8666,  00005 ,24/01/2016
00001,5bef8666,  00001 ,24/01/2016
00002,5bef8666,  00002 ,24/01/2016 
00003,5bef8666,  00003 ,24/01/2016
00004,5bef8666,  00004 ,24/01/2016
```

***Result***

```
DocID, DocTypeID, Invoice, Invoice_Date
00005,  5bef8666,   00005, 24/01/2016
```

This is what I have tried so far with no result.

```
SELECT *
FROM   Documents d1
WHERE  d1.DocTypeID = ' 5bef8666'
       AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                       FROM   Documents d2
                       WHERE  d2.DocTypeID = '923847f9'
                       and d2.Invoice = d1.Invoice);
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please post the attempts you have tried, and explain where it goes wrong

Comment: @user3309798 Simplest where clause `Where DocTypeID  = '5bef8666'`

Comment: What is the use of where clause in SQL?

Comment: Read about EXCEPT, NOT EXISTS & NOT IN.

Comment: I have update my Attempts, please see above.

Comment: See [this recent answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34993300/3404097).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this,

```
Declare @Documents table(
DocID varchar(10),DocTypeID varchar(10),Invoice varchar(10),Invoice_Date  varchar(10))

insert into @documents values
('00001','923847f9','00001','24/01/2016'),
('00002','923847f9','00002','24/01/2016'),
('00003','923847f9','00003','24/01/2016'),
('00004','923847f9','00004','24/01/2016'),
('00005','5bef8666','00005','24/01/2016'),
('00001','5bef8666','00001','24/01/2016'),
('00002','5bef8666','00002','24/01/2016'),
('00003','5bef8666','00003','24/01/2016'),
('00004','5bef8666','00004','24/01/2016')

SELECT *
FROM   @documents d1
WHERE  d1.DocTypeID = '5bef8666'
       AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                       FROM   @documents d2
                       WHERE  d2.doctypeid = '923847f9'
                              AND d1.docid = d2.docid)
```

Comment: Hi @NewUser, The above gives me Zero entries, but I know I have 1 records that does not show in DoctypeID  923847f9 but its in 5bef8666??

Comment: I have edited my answer please check the demo now. The query is right. but you have given an additional space in the where clause filter.(d1.DocTypeID = ' 5bef8666'). Please remove the space before 5bef8666.

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
select a.* from Documents a left join Documents b
on a.DocID = b.DocID
where a.DocTypeID="5bef8666"
and b.DocTypeID is null
```

Comment: This query also does not pull the desired result. if you look at the invoice column, you will see that invoice 0005 does not appear in 923847f9 but it appears in 5bef8666.

Comment: the result was zero records found.

Comment: try to change the where clause to: where a.DocTypeID="5bef8666"
and (b.DocTypeID is null or b.DocTypeID="5bef8666").

Comment: this runs and runs, but does not return result.