# SQL not exists self-join

Tags: sql

I've got a table which stores all letters sent out to customers. I need to run a query to select all account_id's that have received letter_2 but not letter_1. So for example the below results should be accounts 2 & 3.

```
Account_ID Letter_Type
1          Letter_1
1          Letter_2
1          Letter_3
1          Letter_2
2          Letter_2
2          Letter_3
3          Letter_2
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: and what have you tried? Where do you get stuck at? this is not a "write code on my behalf" site ;)

Comment: Apologies, for the record I had tried self-joins with not exists as the poorly worded title suggests... a_horse_with_no_name has "written the code on my behalf" perfectly. Many thanks!

Comment: You should always post your try outs, that way we can tell you where you were wrong and what is the proper way to do it(since there are probably more then 1 ways)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A straightforward way of doing this, is to use `except`:

```
select account_id 
from the_table 
where letter_type = 'Letter_2' 
except 
select account_id 
from the_table 
where letter_type = 'Letter_1'
```

An anti-join using `not exists` would look like this:

```
select t1.account_id 
from the_table t1
where t1.letter_type = 'Letter_2' 
  and not exists (select *
                  from the_table t2
                  where t2.letter_type = 'Letter_1' and 
                    and t1.account_id = t2.account_id);
```

You didn't state your DBMS, but the above is standard ANSI SQL